# NullReferenceException when recording with NAudio (in c#)

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, naudio

I am trying to record voice using NAudio in C# and I am stuck at two places:

*`1. A crash:`*

With a slightly modified form of code from [THIS SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985512/recording-with-naudio-using-c) page, I am getting a `NullReferenceException`. Here is the crash log:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.Callback(IntPtr waveInHandle, WaveMessage message, IntPtr userData, WaveHeader waveHeader, IntPtr reserved)
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

and the code is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using NAudio.Wave;

public class FOO
{
    static WaveIn s_WaveIn;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        init();
        Application.Run();
    }

    public static void record()
    {
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to START Recording.\n");
        Console.ReadLine();

        s_WaveIn.StartRecording();

        Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to STOP recording.\n");
        Console.ReadLine();

        s_WaveIn.StopRecording();
    }
    }

    public static void DeviceInit(int rate, int channels)
    {
    s_WaveIn = new WaveIn();
    s_WaveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(rate, channels);

    s_WaveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 1000;
    s_WaveIn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(SendCaptureSamples);
    }

    public static void init()
    {
    DeviceInit(44100, 2);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate() {
        record();
        });
    t1.Start();
    }

    static void SendCaptureSamples(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Bytes recorded: {0}", e.BytesRecorded);
    }
}
```

Most of the times, this happens when I start recording THIRD time. Any idea what could be causing this?

`*2. Modifying rate and channels at runtime.*`

In my actual code, I am resetting wave format using `s_WaveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(new_rate, new_channels);` before calling `StartRecording()`. I am not calling `Dispose()` because that would require resetting the `DataAvailable` callback, and for that, I would need another message loop. Is this approach correct or should I first call Dispose and then reinitialize s_WaveIn with new format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems that DataAvailable callback is getting called even when buffer is null.

I modified a function in `WaveIn.cs` file and its working fine now. I am not sure if this is correct, but for now, this is working for me.

```
private void Callback(IntPtr waveInHandle, WaveInterop.WaveMessage message, IntPtr userData, WaveHeader waveHeader, IntPtr reserved)
{
    if (message == WaveInterop.WaveMessage.WaveInData)
    {
    GCHandle hBuffer = (GCHandle)waveHeader.userData;
    WaveInBuffer buffer = (WaveInBuffer)hBuffer.Target;
if (buffer != null)
{
    if (DataAvailable != null)
    {
    DataAvailable(this, new WaveInEventArgs(buffer.Data, buffer.BytesRecorded));
    }
    if (recording)
    {
    buffer.Reuse();
    }
}
else
{
    if (RecordingStopped != null)
    {
    RecordingStopped(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your `Main` method looks odd. What is the thread for?

Just use this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    init();
    Application.Run();
}
```

Your `init` method also runs the application. Why?
Try changing it to:

```
public static void init()
{
    DeviceInit(44100, 2);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate() {
        record();
    });
    t1.Start();
}
```

`return;` is not needed at the end of a method returning `void`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes 'Application.Run' was not required in `init`. Fixed that. I reduced my original code keeping only the required things to post here on SO and missed to remove the thread creation in `Main`. Removed that also. But I believe, these changes have nothing to do with the crash I mentioned. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it has to be done in this way:

```
GCHandle hBuffer = (GCHandle)waveHeader.userData;
WaveInBuffer buffer = (WaveInBuffer)hBuffer.Target;

if (buffer == null)
{
    return; // with this new line, everything works fine
}

if (DataAvailable != null)
{
    DataAvailable(this, new WaveInEventArgs(buffer.Data, buffer.BytesRecorded));
}

if (recording)
{
    buffer.Reuse();
}
else
{
    if (RecordingStopped != null)
    {
        RecordingStopped(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same NullReferenceException. The author did not add lines to the proposed class **WaveIn**.
Such use is not provided, as I understand it. Author library in the examples does not calls **StopRecording ()**, and just stops to record incoming information, but continues to process it (for example to measure the volume), and calls **StopRecording ()** for a complete stop to recive data to the data **WaveIn**.
Thus, I believe that it is necessary to use a new WaveIn after calling **StopRecording ()**.