# NAudio record never receiving a sample

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm attempting the simplest possible NAudio example to record from an input device but for some reason I can't get the DataAvailable callback function to be called.

In the example below a break point on Do Something never gets hit.

```
WaveIn waveIn = new WaveIn();
waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
waveIn.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler(waveIn_RecordingStopped);
waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
waveIn.StartRecording();

private void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
   Do Something
}
```

I've checked, re-checked and re-re-checked that the settings are exactly the same as those used by the NAudio VoiceRecorder test application which is able to record audio fine with the exact same settings.

The only difference is my test application is a console application rather than a WPF app. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is because it is a console app, and the WaveIn class uses Windows messages as callbacks. If you are able to download and build the [very latest source code from codeplex](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), you can use the brand new `WaveInEvent` class (added 6 Mar 2012), which does not rely on a Windows message loop.

Alternatively, if you are familiar with installing pre-release packages using NuGet, you can install the latest [NAudio prerelease](https://nuget.org/packages/NAudio/) (currently [1.5.4-beta](https://nuget.org/packages/NAudio/1.5.4-beta)) which has this class in.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, have you verified your device is valid?

Try something like this;

```
        int waveInDevices = WaveIn.DeviceCount;
        for (int waveInDevice = 0; waveInDevice < waveInDevices; waveInDevice++)
        {
            WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveInDevice);
            MessageBox.Show("Device " + waveInDevice + ": " + deviceInfo.ProductName +
                ", " + deviceInfo.Channels + " channels");
        }
```

to verify you have a recording device.

Comment: Yes I did do that and device 0 is definitely available.